# Exception handling: finally-like idiom for caught exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Let's say we have a situation as follows:

```
try:
    <this code might fail and raise one of a, b or c>
except a:
    <something specific for a>
except b:
    <something specific for b>
```

and we want to add a bit of logic to the code that:

1. executes only when either `a` or `b` were raised in the `try` block
2. leaves `c` unhandled

Something like the `finally` clause but only for caught exceptions, or an *inverse* `else`.. Is there a standard schema used in Python for that?

Comment: You can group exceptions together `except (a, b) as e:`

Comment: @JoshuaNixon the code executed in the `except` clauses is generally different and thus I can't see how grouping can be elegantly implemented here.

Comment: You could just put the logic into a function and just call it in the a and b exception handler

Comment: I don't think there is anything like what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @Joshua's idea, the best I can come up with is the following:

```
try:
    <this code might fail and raise one of a, b or c>
except (a, b) as error:
    if isinstance(error, a):
        <something specific for a>
    elif isinstance(error, b):
        <something specific for b>
    <common logic for caught exceptions>
```

This is more than good enough for my current needs. Thanks!